# How to reset/remove CSS styles for a specific element or selector only

Tags: css

Is there a CSS rule available that will remove any styles previously set in the stylesheet for a particular element?

A good use example might be in a mobile-first RWD site where much of the styling used for a particular element in the small-screen views needs 'resetting' or removing for the same element in the desktop view.

A CSS rule that could achieve something like:

```
.element {
  all: none;
}
```

Example usage:

```
/* mobile first */
.element {
   margin: 0 10;
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   z-index: 50;
   display: block;
   etc..
   etc..
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .element {
    all: none;
  }
}
```

So we could quickly remove or re-set styling without having to declare every property.

Comment: The way to do it is to restrict it in the first place with media queries

Comment: There *is* a property called `all` that is being proposed for resetting *all* CSS properties for a given element to certain CSS-wide values - the value you want to use would be `unset`, which resets a property to either its inherited value if it inherits by default, or otherwise, its initial value. No word on implementation, but it's nice to know somebody has thought of it.

Comment: Here is a 2015 tweet to that effect: https://twitter.com/LeaVerou/status/577390241763467264

Comment: Not an answer to this specific question but related: To attach an element to the DOM that is unaffected by styles of the rest of the document, shadow doms can be used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM

Answer (score 812, accepted):

The CSS property `all` has a keyword `initial` that sets the [CSS property to the initial value as defined in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#keywords). The `all` keyword has [broad browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value) except for the IE and Opera Mini families.

```
/* basic modern patch */

#reset-this-root {
    all: unset;
}
```

or

```
#reset-this-root {
    all: initial;
}
```

Since IE's lack of support may cause issue here are some of the ways you can reset some CSS properties to their initial values:

```
.reset-this {
    animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-name : none;
    animation-play-state : running;
    animation-timing-function : ease;
    backface-visibility : visible;
    background : 0;
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-clip : border-box;
    background-color : transparent;
    background-image : none;
    background-origin : padding-box;
    background-position : 0 0;
    background-position-x : 0;
    background-position-y : 0;
    background-repeat : repeat;
    background-size : auto auto;
    border : 0;
    border-style : none;
    border-width : medium;
    border-color : inherit;
    border-bottom : 0;
    border-bottom-color : inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-style : none;
    border-bottom-width : medium;
    border-collapse : separate;
    border-image : none;
    border-left : 0;
    border-left-color : inherit;
    border-left-style : none;
    border-left-width : medium;
    border-radius : 0;
    border-right : 0;
    border-right-color : inherit;
    border-right-style : none;
    border-right-width : medium;
    border-spacing : 0;
    border-top : 0;
    border-top-color : inherit;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border-top-style : none;
    border-top-width : medium;
    bottom : auto;
    box-shadow : none;
    box-sizing : content-box;
    caption-side : top;
    clear : none;
    clip : auto;
    color : inherit;
    columns : auto;
    column-count : auto;
    column-fill : balance;
    column-gap : normal;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor;
    column-rule-color : currentColor;
    column-rule-style : none;
    column-rule-width : none;
    column-span : 1;
    column-width : auto;
    content : normal;
    counter-increment : none;
    counter-reset : none;
    cursor : auto;
    direction : ltr;
    display : inline;
    empty-cells : show;
    float : none;
    font : normal;
    font-family : inherit;
    font-size : medium;
    font-style : normal;
    font-variant : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    height : auto;
    hyphens : none;
    left : auto;
    letter-spacing : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    list-style : none;
    list-style-image : none;
    list-style-position : outside;
    list-style-type : disc;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    max-height : none;
    max-width : none;
    min-height : 0;
    min-width : 0;
    opacity : 1;
    orphans : 0;
    outline : 0;
    outline-color : invert;
    outline-style : none;
    outline-width : medium;
    overflow : visible;
    overflow-x : visible;
    overflow-y : visible;
    padding : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    padding-left : 0;
    padding-right : 0;
    padding-top : 0;
    page-break-after : auto;
    page-break-before : auto;
    page-break-inside : auto;
    perspective : none;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
    position : static;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
    right : auto;
    tab-size : 8;
    table-layout : auto;
    text-align : inherit;
    text-align-last : auto;
    text-decoration : none;
    text-decoration-color : inherit;
    text-decoration-line : none;
    text-decoration-style : solid;
    text-indent : 0;
    text-shadow : none;
    text-transform : none;
    top : auto;
    transform : none;
    transform-style : flat;
    transition : none;
    transition-delay : 0s;
    transition-duration : 0s;
    transition-property : none;
    transition-timing-function : ease;
    unicode-bidi : normal;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    visibility : visible;
    white-space : normal;
    widows : 0;
    width : auto;
    word-spacing : normal;
    z-index : auto;
    /* basic modern patch */
    all: initial;
    all: unset;
}
```

- [Relevant GitHub repo with a *December 2017* more exhaustive list](https://github.com/iamstarkov/css-initials)
- [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value)
- [Related from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial_value)
- [Related W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial)

With all this said, I don't think a CSS reset is something feasible unless we end up with only one web browser, if the 'default' is set by browser in the end.

Comment: i think this is correct in principle, but individual mileage may vary. For example certain elements like textarea by default have a border, applying this reset will render those textarea's border less. So it not a true reset. I ended up using it for only certain properties which I cared about. You can also combine it with the * selector to reset all elements or reset all elements inside a specific element.

Comment: @user566245 Applying this with a * selector will kill your browser AND a kitten. This is NOT a true reset. True reset just don't exist.

Comment: You can use the [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) property, which is supported by [all modern browsers](https://twitter.com/LeaVerou/status/577390241763467264).

Comment: WARNING: You do NOT want to ever use "initial" like this! This will erase most web browser's default UA style sheet for the element, which means things like block-level elements now use "display:inline", etc. etc. Most web developers do not understand that most elements have no styling until a default user agent style sheet (that comes with browsers) is applied. This sheet is what gives elements a base style before the author applies their own styles over it. If you use "initial" you erase all styles and cannot get the elements style back on your web page for the viewer.

Answer (score 266):

The [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) property does this, and works like this:

CSS:

```css
#someselector {
  all: initial;
}

#someselector * {
  all: unset
}
```

SCSS:

```scss
#someselector {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

- Works in all major browsers that are still supported. Does not work in Internet Explorer, if you still have to maintain that.

Comment: I just read "On inherited properties, the initial value may be surprising and you should consider using the inherit, unset, or revert keywords instead. Also, does this comes back to browser-specific? Where this initial initial is .. set by the ... ? DDT?

Comment: ```all: revert;``` sounds really useful for components/widgets in the MDN docs, but it is not clear from @AsimKT 's comment how it should be used. Can you elaborate? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert

Comment: What if you want to add _some_ style to #someselector (and reset whatever else is set)? I tried the initial & unset thing in addition with something else (color or border) but it doesn't work

Comment: To reset all styles except some of them, one may do this(for example, let's say we want to keep the font-size at 18px): `#selector { all: initial; font-size: 18px; }`. Works for me like charm!

Comment: I would recommend trying `revert` instead of `unset`, otherwise user-agent defaults for things like `<table>` and `<details>` all fall apart.

Answer (score 83):

Use `all: revert` or `all: unset`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert):

> The revert keyword works exactly the same as [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) in many cases. The
> only difference is for properties that have values set by the browser
> or by custom stylesheets created by users (set on the browser side).

You need **"A CSS rule available that would remove any styles previously set in the stylesheet for a particular element."**

So, if the element have a class name like `remove-all-styles`:

HTML:

```
<div class="remove-all-styles other-classe another-class"> 
   <!-- content -->
   <p class="text-red other-some-styles"> My text </p>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
  .remove-all-styles {
    all: revert;
  }
```

This will reset all styles applied by `other-class`, `another-class` and all other inherited and applied styles to that `div`.

Or in your case:

```
/* mobile first */
.element {
   margin: 0 10;
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   z-index: 50;
   display: block;
   etc..
   etc..
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .element {
    all: revert;
  }
}
```

Will do.

If we want to **isolate embedded widgets/components from the styles of the page that contains them**, we could write:

```
.isolated-component {
 all: revert;
}
```

Which will reverts all author styles (i.e. developer CSS) to user styles (styles which the user of our website sets - the less likely scenario) or to user-agent styles itself if no user styles set.

Answer (score 29):

**The quick answer is use `"all:revert"`**

```
.element {
  all:revert;
}
```

**`all:revert` will RESET all the style properties on your element back to the original browser default UA style sheet property values, or whatever is styled in the parent body element.** But it will not **ERASE** style properties like `initial`, returning them to a completely unstyled state.

In the case of text or inherited properties, `"revert"` resets your element's CSS property back to its inherited values coming from your "body" element or the browser's default UA style value, not to the property’s base style. For a non-inherited property, it resets it back again to the browser's UA default style sheet and not to the property’s base style. "all" allows all properties to be affected. This is likely what you want to see.

**Problems Using `"all:revert"`**

`"all:revert"` is a newer CSS declaration that only works in more modern HTML5 browsers (post-2015), and even then has very poor support in certain modern browsers like Internet Explorer 1-11, Edge Trident, and some mobile browsers. None of the older, non-HTML5 browsers (pre-2010) will understand this declaration, so it will be ignored by a wide range of browsers, old and new. (See my mixed CSS solution down below that has fixes for Internet Explorer).

**Problems Using `"initial"` and `"unset"`**

You can use `"initial"` or `"unset"` but you have to manually apply them for each property, and what is even worse, they will not return properties to the element's default display values as set by each browser's default UA style sheet, but **`"initial"` will essentially erase the element's property values** and create a completely *unstyled* element. For example, "display:block" on block level elements will be erased. Because the style property still needs a default value of some kind all block and non-block level elements with "display" will be changed to "display:inline" when you use "display:initial". You do not want to ever do this as it erases your styles AND the browser's default UA element styles from the selected element completely.

`"unset"` works close to the same, but in the case of inherited text-based CSS properties its properties inherit whatever is in the parents above the element (could be the browsers default UA style or whatever is in the HTML parent above), but for non-inherited properties works like `"initial"`.

My recommendation is AVOID using `all:initial` or any form of `initial` in CSS unless you are trying to erase an individual CSS property you cannot erase in any other way. Why? `initial` erases not just the styles you applied but all styles the browsers default UA style sheet applied. `all:revert` will not do this. In terms of using `initial`, it does have better support in Internet Explorer, as does its cousin, `inherit`. But only IE8+ understands `initial`. So, there are a wide range of problems with this property value. It is not reliable.

The reason *CSS works this way* is all HTML elements come without any styling until the browser applies a default user-agent style sheet that gives all the HTML elements a base style. All HTML elements really have NO STYLES, and other than "replaced" elements like textarea and buttons, look alike until each browser's default UA sheet is applied. "initial" and "unset" would wipe away most of that from the browser. `"revert"` at least preserves their basic style set applied by the user's browser, and is therefore superior to `"initial"` and `"unset"`. You can review all the various default style sheets that come with browsers in the link below.

A LIST OF DEFAULT BROWSER STYLE SHEETS:
https://meiert.com/en/blog/user-agent-style-sheets/

**NOW FOR AN EVEN BETTER SOLUTION**

There are two ideas here being confused:

1. The first idea is about "returning" styles back to a browser's UA style sheet value set (the style sheet that comes with the browser on install that defines what each element looks like). Each browser defines its own styles as to how elements should look by default. This idea is about returning all page styles back to each browsers native element styles.
2. The second idea is about "resetting" all default browser styles to a common look and feel shared by all browsers. People build special "reset" sheets to try and align all the browser elements to a common agreed on style, universally. This has nothing to do with a browsers default UA styles and more about "cleaning up" and aligning all browsers to a common base style. This is an additive process only.

Those are two very different concepts people here are confusing.

Because each browser often had default, out-of-the-box element and layout styles that looked slightly different, people came up with the idea of the "reset" or "reboot" style sheet to align all the browsers BEFORE applying custom CSS. Bootstrap now does this, for example. But that had nothing to do with people wanting to return to the browser's default look and feel.

The problem was not the building of these custom "reset" style sheets, it is figuring out what the default CSS was for each browser and each element BEFORE any styles were applied. Most found out you cant rebuild an existing clean cascade until you "clear out" all styles already applied. But how to get back to the default browser styling?

For some this meant going beyond returning the elements to the browsers UA style sheet that comes with the browser. Many wanted to reset back to "initial" property values which has NOTHING to do with the browser's default style, but really the properties defaults. This is dangerous as in the case of "display" pushes block level elements back to "inline" and breaks table layouts and other things.

So I do NOT agree with users here using "initial" to reset anything or custom reset classes that change every property back to some arbitrary base value set.

A better solution to me has always been to attempt to try and **return all core element styling back to the browser's UA style sheet values**, which is what all our end-users are using anyway. If you are creating a new website, you don't have to do this. You start with the browser's default styles and style over them. Its only after you've added third-party CSS products, or found yourself with complicated CSS cascades, that you want to figure out how to return to the browser default style sheet values.

For this reason, **I'm for creating your own "reset" sheet to reset all the elements to one common style** first that's shared by all old and new browsers as a first step. You then have a solid framework that's much easier to revert to without going back to the browser defaults. You are simply building on a reset common core set of element style values. Once build your own "reset" sheet, one that ADDS not ALTERS the browsers UA styles, you have a site that's very easy to modify.

The only problem remaining then is when you have a site that does NOT have such a reset sheet, or have that complex third party CSS and need to try and return to the browser UA styles. How do you do that?

I realize Internet Explorer has forced us too manually reset every property to get back to any sort of reset. But pushing those property values all back to "initial" destroys the browser UA style sheet values completely! BAD IDEA! A better way is to simply use "all:revert" for non-IE  browsers on every element using a wildcard, and "inherit" only for a handful of inherited root-level properties found in the "html" and "body" elements that affect all inheriting children in the page. (see below). I'm NOT for these huge resets of properties using "initial" or going back to some imaginary standard we assume all browsers or IE will use. For starters "initial" has poor support in IE and doesn't reset values to element defaults, only property defaults. But its also pointless if you are going to create a reset sheet to align all elements to a common style. In that case its pointless to clear out styles and start over.

So here is my simple solution that in most cases does enough to reset what text-based values sift down into IE from the root and use "all:revert" for all non-IE browsers to force non-inherited values back to the browser's UA style sheet completely, giving you a true restart. This does not interfere with higher level classes and styles layered over your element styles, which should always be the goal anyway. Its why I'm NOT for these custom reset classes which is tedious and unnecessary and doesn't return the element to its browser UA style anyway. Notice the slightly more selective selectors below which would write over, for example, Bootstrap's "reboot" style values, returning them to the browser default styles. These would not reset element styles on elements for IE, of course, but for non-IE browsers and most inheritable text styling it would return elements in most agents to the UA style sheets that come with browsers:

```
    :root, html {
        display: block;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        font-weight: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: inherit;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: inherit;
        all: revert;
    }
    
    html body {
        display: block;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        font-weight: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        margin: inherit;
        padding: inherit;
        color: inherit;
        text-align: inherit;
        background-color: inherit;
        background: inherit;
        all: revert;
    }
    
    /* This rule attempts to manually reset all elements back to the 
    UA browser style sheet using "revert" and the "wildcard" (*)
    which resets all properties on all HTML elements.
    This would overwrite most of Bootstraps "reboot" styles
    on elements, for example.
    Note: This selector should be ignored by IE. */

    html body * {
        all: revert;
    }
```

You can also use my free [Universal CSS Framework](https://github.com/EMStokely/UniversalCSSFramework) which implements revert in it's reset style sheets.

Answer (score 28):

**The Problem**

You need to insert markup into an HTML document, and it needs to look a specific way.  Furthermore, you do not own this document, so you cannot change existing style rules.  You have no idea what the style sheets *could* be, or what they may change to.

Use cases for this are when you are providing a displayable component for unknown 3rd party websites to use.  Examples of this would be:

1. An ad tag
2. Building a browser extension that inserts content
3. Any type of widget

**Simplest Fix**

Put everything in an iframe.  This has it's own set of limitations:

1. Cross Domain limitations: Your content will not have access to the original document at all.  You cannot overlay content, modify the DOM, etc.
2. Display Limitations: Your content is locked inside of a rectangle.

If your content *can* fit into a box, you can get around problem #1 by having your content write an iframe and explicitly set the content, thus skirting around the issue, since the iframe and document will share the same domain.

**CSS Solution**

The best you can do is explicitly override all possible properties that can be overridden, and override them to what you *think* their default value should be.

Even when you override, *there is no way to ensure a more targeted CSS rule won't override yours*. The best you can do here is to have your override rules target as specifically as possible and hope the parent document doesn't accidentally best it: use an obscure or random ID on your content's parent element, and use !important on all property value definitions.

Comment: You can use the [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) property, which is supported by [all modern browsers](https://twitter.com/LeaVerou/status/577390241763467264).

Comment: The proper solution to this general problem is to use [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: This is a very real issue, but only ever exists as a result of poorly developed CSS in the first place. If you are creating markup and CSS, if you have done it properly, none of your styles should bleed into a third party app. If I were responsible for the CSS spec, I would not be embarrassed, but upset people are brutally misusing what I had created.

Comment: @DanDascalescu The all property isn't going to revert to the "default" browser css styles. It's only going to revert to the "initial" css styles. The difference is that one styles the page as if no CSS exists, the other one will use the element styles (i,e, `p { color: blue}` won't be reset)

Answer (score 11):

another ways:

1) include the css code(file) of [Yahoo CSS reset](http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset-context/cssreset-context-min.css) and then put everything inside this DIV:

```
<div class="yui3-cssreset">
    <!-- Anything here would be reset-->
</div>
```

2) or use

- https://cssreset.com/scripts/vanilla-css-un-reset/
- https://cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/
- https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/
- https://cssreset.com/scripts/tripoli-css-reset-david-hellsing/
- https://cssreset.com/scripts/normalize-css/

Answer (score 7):

If you happen to be using sass in a build system, one way to do this that will work in all the major browsers is to wrap all your style imports with a :not() selector like so...

```
:not(.disable-all-styles) {
  @import 'my-sass-file';
  @import 'my-other-sass-file';
}
```

Then you can use the disable class on a container and the sub-content won't have any of your styles.

```
<div class="disable-all-styles">
  <p>Nothing in this div is affected by my sass styles.</p>
</div>
```

Of course all your styles will now be prepended with the :not() selector, so it's a little fugly, but works well.

Answer (score 6):

I do not recommend using the answer that has been marked as correct here. It is a huge blob of CSS which tries to cover everything.

I would suggest that you evaluate how to remove the style from an element on a per case basis.

Lets say for SEO purposes you need to include an H1 on a page which has no actual heading in the design. You might want to make the nav link of that page an H1 but ofcourse you do not want that navigation link to display as a giant H1 on the page.

What you should do is wrap that element in an h1 tag and inspect it. See what CSS styles are being applied specifically to the h1 element.

Lets say I see the following styles applied to the element.

```
//bootstrap.min.css:1
h1 {
    font-size: 65px;
    font-family: 'rubikbold'!important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

//bootstrap.min.css:1
h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}

//bootstrap.min.css:1
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

//bootstrap.min.css:1
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: inherit;
}

//bootstrap.min.css:1
h1 {
    margin: .67em 0;
    font-size: 2em;
}

//user agent stylesheet
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now you need to pin point the exact style which are applied to the H1 and unset them in a css class. This would look something like the following:

```
.no-style-h1 {
    font-size: unset !important;
    font-family: unset !important;
    font-weight: unset !important;
    font-style: unset !important;
    text-transform: unset !important;
    margin-top: unset !important;
    margin-bottom: unset !important;
    line-height: unset !important;
    color: unset !important;
    margin: unset !important;
    display: unset !important;
    -webkit-margin-before: unset !important;
    -webkit-margin-after: unset !important;
    -webkit-margin-start: unset !important;
    -webkit-margin-end: unset !important;
}
```

This is much cleaner and does not just dump a random blob of code into your css which you don't know what it's actually doing.

Now you can add this class to your h1

```
<h1 class="no-style-h1">
     Title
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my specific scenario i wanted to skip applying common styles to a specific part of the page, better illustrated like this:

```
<body class='common-styles'>
    <div id='header'>Wants common styles</div>
    <div id='container'>Does NOT want common styles</div>
    <div id='footer'>Wants common styles</div>
</body>
```

After messing with CSS reset which didn't bring much success (mainly because of rules precedence and complex stylesheet hierarchy), brought up ubiquitous jQuery to the rescue, which did the job very quickly and reasonably dirty:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('common-styles');
    $('#header,#footer').addClass('common-styles');
});
```

(Now tell how evil it is to use JS to deal with CSS :-) )

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is coming here looking for an answer that utilizes `iframe` here it is

```
<iframe srcdoc="<html><body>your-html-here</body></html>" />
```

https://caniuse.com/iframe-srcdoc

Comment: How does this answer the question of removing CSS styles from a specific element? This answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**BETTER SOLUTION**

Download "copy/paste" stylesheet‎ to reset css properties to default (UA style):
https://github.com/monmomo04/resetCss.git

Thanks@Milche Patern!

I was really looking for reset/default style properties value. My first try was to copy the computed value from the browser Dev tool of the root(html) element. But as it computed, it would have looked/worked different on every system.

For those who encounter a browser crash when trying to use the asterisk * to reset the style of the children elements, and as I knew it didn't work for you, I have replaced the asterisk "*" with  all the HTML tags name instead. The browser didn't crash; I am on Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m.

At last, it's good to mention that those properties will reset the style to the default style of topest root element  but not to the initial value for each HTML element. ‎So to correct this, I have taken the "user-agent" styles of webkit based browser and implemented it under the "reset-this" class.

Useful link:

Download "copy/paste" stylesheet‎ to reset css properties to default (UA style):
https://github.com/monmomo04/resetCss.git

User-agent style:
[Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements/6867287#6867287)
http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

Css specifity (pay attention to specifity) :
https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

https://github.com/monmomo04/resetCss.git

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned mobile-first sites... For a responsive design, it's certainly possible to override small-screen styles with large-screen styles. But you might not need to.

Try this:

```
.thisClass {
    /* Rules for all window sizes. */
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .thisClass {
        /* Rules for only small browser windows. */
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 960px) {
    .thisClass {
        /* Rules for only medium browser windows. */
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 961px) {
    .thisClass {
        /* Rules for only large browser windows. */
    }
}
```

Those media queries don't overlap, so their rules don't override each other. This makes it easier to maintain each set of styles separately.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you trying to figure out how to actually remove the styling from the element only, without removing the css from the files, this solution works with jquery:

```
$('.selector').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set your CSS within classes, 
you can easly remove them using jQuery removeClass() Method. 
The code below removes .element class:

```
    <div class="element">source</div>   
    <div class="destination">destination</div>
      <script>
        $(".element").removeClass();
      </script>
```

If no parameter is specified, this method will remove 
ALL class names from the selected elements.

Answer (score -1):

I was using Material-Tailwind for my project and was struggling to remove the default css of an element. SO I simply added style={{all: "revert"}} as the attribute in my jsx and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

As other answers have mentioned, the CSS property `all` set to the value `unset` seems to override all CSS properties without knowing which properties are in play. However, this did not work for me while adding custom CSS in a Wordpress site, as the `all` property was not recognized by the Wordpress custom CSS editor, and did not reflect changes in Microsoft Edge. Instead, what worked for me was a brute-force override, that is, to identify every property used in the webpage element and manually reset each one of them. The way to identify the CSS properties being used by an element is to inspect the element with your web browser, and go through the 'Styles' tab.

Comment: "the CSS editor" What editor are you using? And why would that matter when it's the _browser_ where it needs to work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @TylerH You're right, I've edited my answer to make it a bit clearer. I was using the Wordpress 'Additional CSS' editor to add my CSS. This has a highlight feature which threw an error for the 'all' property. I went ahead and saved the CSS anyway, but the expected changes to be made by ```all : unset``` did not reflect in the website opened through Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score -3):

Any chance you're looking for the !important rule? It doesn't undo all declarations but it provides a way to override them.

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do with specificity.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception

Comment: !Importants is not the way to go. It's to bold to use and you should only use it as a last resort (for instance, when a plugin used an !important too)