# Remove default browser effects from HTML5 <button>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When Chrome renders a html5 button element it creates a dropshadow and an embossed click effect. How do I get rid of these to leave me with a standard flat button?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15903168/342473

Comment: That seems a crazy solution. Surely it would remove all inherited styles? I only want to stop chrome embossing the element and remove the dropshadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `border:none ;`

Or this  `box-shadow:none ;`

Comment: Fantastic, It looked like it was doing more than adding a border... Thanks