# HTML CSS How to ignore child styles?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm having trouble setting wyziwyg editor in my site (tried at least 20 editors and every of them has same problem: pasting the text from word or even notepad creates unwanted CSS stylings (example: font-size, padding, even color). now I'm looking for a way to create master rule in wrapping div which will ignore every child stylings.

Is there a way to do so?

thanks everyone

Comment: I think you are approaching this the wrong way.  You should instead be filtering out the styles you don't want when pasting.  In fact, most editors should have settings for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Comment: can you suggest good editor? which works in your experience? the main purphose is to post blog news (with Bold,italic, lists, and link options) nothing more needed

Comment: I think you mean wysiwyg

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE for example has an *Paste as plain text* exactly for that. Check it out here: http://www.tinymce.com/, click on *Edit->Paste as plain text*