# CSS media screen remove whole class

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a class called .nav ul li ul working before using @media screen, When I work on media screen I want to disable this class (Don't want css to read it anymore). Is there anyway to do this?
Example

```
.nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: -30px;
  width: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.nav ul li ul {
  Do not do anything, Just ignore the original class
}

}
```

Please note that I still want to display this class But I don't want to give it any properties. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .nav ul li ul {
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 0px;
    }
}
```

This should reset all the properties previously set.

[Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

That link is to a question that has many default property values for css, as there is currently no built in way to reset it to a default.

Comment: Actually I want to display this class, But I don't want to give it any properties.

Comment: In that case I would just reset the properties that you previously set. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can either recopy the same properties:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: -30px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

or just simply don't write that part. It actually worked on the times when I try it.