# Div whose content can't be affected by CSS

Tags: css

It may be a rather silly question, but I'm wondering... is there a way to make the content of a div **completely immune to the CSS linked to the HTML**?

I have something like this:

**CSS**

```
...
p{ background-color: pink; }
...
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      ...
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Some text</p> <!--This should have pink background-->
      <div class="immunediv">
         <p>Some more text</p> <!--This shouldn't be blue-->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** That's just an example. What I want is ALL tags inside **.immunediv** to be immune to styles. Like...

```
<div class="immunediv">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <p>This is a <b>test</b></p>
   <a href="#">And this is a link</a>
</div>
```

Even if **b**, **h1**, **p** and **a** are styled in the CSS they shouldn't take that style since they're inside **.immunedive** and instead get the default one.

Comment: Did you mean "pink" in your second comment instead of "blue"?

Comment: Generally  !important breakes the Cascading, but you really need to know about every single way your immunediv can be messed up with. So, it's ain't generic.

Comment: You probably want to class pink  .pink { background: pink; } and use <p class="pink">Hello</p> instead of using !importants and "immune divs" (that don't exist and is a huge hack)

Comment: Are you after something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6UEUd/)..?

Comment: Check this out, Josh: http://jsfiddle.net/aMW7g/
I want the "b" and the "p" don't be affected by the CSS.

Comment: @McSullivanD'Ander You had an extra end bracket in there `}`.. http://jsfiddle.net/PMasf/

Comment: `:not(.immunediv) p {

Comment: You can try to use an iFrame for that section. I know its not what you wanted the answer to be. But that would give you the same results. iFrame wont take styles from you current page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update or Change or Remove/Reset Javascript event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007354/update-or-change-or-remove-reset-javascript-event-listener)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:not(.immunediv) p { background-color: pink; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
p {
    background-color: pink;
    color:red;
}
b {
    background-color: blue;   
}
.immunediv * {
    color:inherit;
    background:transparent;
}
```

and html

```
<p>Some text</p>
<b>Hahahaha</b>
<div class="immunediv">
    <p><b>Some</b> more text</p>
</div>
```

you added a bracket extra in JSFiddle

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying something more... universal. Not just specifically for <b> and <p>. Thanks for answering, though, and sorry for the extra bracket :P

Answer (score 0):

By adapting the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903168/1370722), you can reset the style for an element and all its descendants.

```
.immune, .immune * {
    animation : none !important;
    animation-delay : 0 !important;
    animation-direction : normal !important;
    animation-duration : 0 !important;
    animation-fill-mode : none !important;
    animation-iteration-count : 1 !important;
    animation-name : none !important;
    animation-play-state : running !important;
    animation-timing-function : ease !important;
    backface-visibility : visible !important;
    background : 0 !important;
    background-attachment : scroll !important;
    background-clip : border-box !important;
    background-color : transparent !important;
    background-image : none !important;
    background-origin : padding-box !important;
    background-position : 0 0 !important;
    background-position-x : 0 !important;
    background-position-y : 0 !important;
    background-repeat : repeat !important;
    background-size : auto auto !important;
    border : 0 !important;
    border-style : none !important;
    border-width : medium !important;
    border-color : inherit !important;
    border-bottom : 0 !important;
    border-bottom-color : inherit !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0 !important;
    border-bottom-style : none !important;
    border-bottom-width : medium !important;
    border-collapse : separate !important;
    border-image : none !important;
    border-left : 0 !important;
    border-left-color : inherit !important;
    border-left-style : none !important;
    border-left-width : medium !important;
    border-radius : 0 !important;
    border-right : 0 !important;
    border-right-color : inherit !important;
    border-right-style : none !important;
    border-right-width : medium !important;
    border-spacing : 0 !important;
    border-top : 0 !important;
    border-top-color : inherit !important;
    border-top-left-radius : 0 !important;
    border-top-right-radius : 0 !important;
    border-top-style : none !important;
    border-top-width : medium !important;
    bottom : auto !important;
    box-shadow : none !important;
    box-sizing : content-box !important;
    caption-side : top !important;
    clear : none !important;
    clip : auto !important;
    color : inherit !important;
    columns : auto !important;
    column-count : auto !important;
    column-fill : balance !important;
    column-gap : normal !important;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor !important;
    column-rule-color : currentColor !important;
    column-rule-style : none !important;
    column-rule-width : none !important;
    column-span : 1 !important;
    column-width : auto !important;
    content : normal !important;
    counter-increment : none !important;
    counter-reset : none !important;
    cursor : auto !important;
    direction : ltr !important;
    display : inline !important;
    empty-cells : show !important;
    float : none !important;
    font : normal !important;
    font-family : inherit !important;
    font-size : medium !important;
    font-style : normal !important;
    font-variant : normal !important;
    font-weight : normal !important;
    height : auto !important;
    hyphens : none !important;
    left : auto !important;
    letter-spacing : normal !important;
    line-height : normal !important;
    list-style : none !important;
    list-style-image : none !important;
    list-style-position : outside !important;
    list-style-type : disc !important;
    margin : 0 !important;
    margin-bottom : 0 !important;
    margin-left : 0 !important;
    margin-right : 0 !important;
    margin-top : 0 !important;
    max-height : none !important;
    max-width : none !important;
    min-height : 0 !important;
    min-width : 0 !important;
    opacity : 1 !important;
    orphans : 0 !important;
    outline : 0 !important;
    outline-color : invert !important;
    outline-style : none !important;
    outline-width : medium !important;
    overflow : visible !important;
    overflow-x : visible !important;
    overflow-y : visible !important;
    padding : 0 !important;
    padding-bottom : 0 !important;
    padding-left : 0 !important;
    padding-right : 0 !important;
    padding-top : 0 !important;
    page-break-after : auto !important;
    page-break-before : auto !important;
    page-break-inside : auto !important;
    perspective : none !important;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50% !important;
    position : static !important;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019' !important;
    right : auto !important;
    tab-size : 8 !important;
    table-layout : auto !important;
    text-align : inherit !important;
    text-align-last : auto !important;
    text-decoration : none !important;
    text-decoration-color : inherit !important;
    text-decoration-line : none !important;
    text-decoration-style : solid !important;
    text-indent : 0 !important;
    text-shadow : none !important;
    text-transform : none !important;
    top : auto !important;
    transform : none !important;
    transform-style : flat !important;
    transition : none !important;
    transition-delay : 0s !important;
    transition-duration : 0s !important;
    transition-property : none !important;
    transition-timing-function : ease !important;
    unicode-bidi : normal !important;
    vertical-align : baseline !important;
    visibility : visible !important;
    white-space : normal !important;
    widows : 0 !important;
    width : auto !important;
    word-spacing : normal !important;
    z-index : auto !important;
}
```

*Note 1:* Buttons and form controls will lose browser-specific styling

*Note 2*: In some cases, it will not work. Even though adding `!important` to a rule gives it a higher priority, another rule (in the original css) might have an even higher priority (for example: another rule with `!important`)

In that case, you will need to create a specific override

```
  /* original css */
  #header { 
     border: 1px solid black !important;
  }

  /* css reset (from above) */
  .immune, .immune * {
     border: none !important;
  }

  /* override */
  #header.immune, .immune #header {
     border: none !important;
  }
```