# Update or Change or Remove/Reset Javascript event listener

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I'm working on a small html5 canvas drawing library and I'm having a slight problem, here's the code (fiddle below):

```
var drawr = {
init: function (canvas_id, canvasWidth, canvasHeight) { //height & width are optional
    this.canvas_id = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    this.canvasWidth = canvasWidth;
    this.canvasHeight = canvasHeight;
    this.context = this.canvas_id.getContext('2d');

    if (canvasWidth) {
        this.canvas_id.width = canvasWidth;
    }

    if (canvasHeight) {
        this.canvas_id.height = canvasHeight;
    }

},

//magic line drawing function
ctx: function (a, b, x, y, dLineColor, dLineWidth) { //lineWidth & lineColor are optional; defaults are 1px & 'black'
    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(a, b);
    this.context.lineTo(x, y);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.strokeStyle = dLineColor;
    this.context.lineWidth = dLineWidth;
    this.context.stroke();

},

//destroy event handlers to prevent drawing
destroy: function () {
    //destroy event handlers

},

draw: function (lineColor, lineWidth) {
    //create some utilities for draw function to use
    var localPen = {};
    var drawing = false;
    var canvasPos = {
        x: this.canvas_id.offsetLeft,
        y: this.canvas_id.offsetTop
    }

    //initiate event handlers
    this.canvas_id.addEventListener('mousedown', addDraw, false);

    function addDraw(e) {
        drawing = true;
        console.log(drawing);
        localPen.x = e.pageX - canvasPos.x;
        localPen.y = e.pageY - canvasPos.y;
    };


    this.canvas_id.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        var drawTo = {
            x: e.pageX - canvasPos.x,
            y: e.pageY - canvasPos.y
        }
        if (drawing) {
            drawr.ctx(localPen.x, localPen.y, drawTo.x, drawTo.y, lineColor, lineWidth);
        }

        localPen.x = drawTo.x;
        localPen.y = drawTo.y;

    });

    this.canvas_id.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        drawing = false;
    });

    this.canvas_id.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (e) {
        drawing = false;
    });
    }

}

    drawr.init('my_canvas');
    drawr.draw('red', 10);
    drawr.draw('blue', 5);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is this: when I call `drawr.draw();` a second (or third, etc) for it to override the previous function. How should I go about this? As you can see in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle_me_this/cbpvsguL/75/) each instance simultaneously runs.

Feel free to edit, update, delete, yell at me for bad code, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A call to `addEventListener` will override the previous one, or a call to `removeEventListener` will remove a listener, only when the handler functions specified for that event type are **strictly equal**. A anonymous function, even if lexically identical, will not be equal to a second anonymous function created during a separate execution  of the method.

Here's one idea: define your handler as a separate function in a closure, as follows:

```
obj = function() {
    function handler() { /* handle the click; "this" is the element */ }

    return {
        draw: function() {
            this.elt.addEventListener('click', handler);
            //draw a bunch of stuff
        },

        undraw: function() {
            this.elt.removeEventListener('click', handler);
            //undraw a bunch of stuff
        }

    };
}();
```

Now, since `handler` is always strictly equal to itself, the `removeEventListener` will successfully remove the handler. Or, a second `addEventListener` will not do anything (just leave the current handler in place).

However, `handler` has no access to the `this` of the object; it will be called with the event's target element as its `this`. In order to get the object's `this` into the event handler, you may be tempted to try

```
this.elt.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(this));
```

but this will fail to accomplish what you want, because the value of `handler.bind(this)` is different each time the method is invoked, so you will again end up with redundant event handlers, or `removeEventListener`s which do not work.

If you really want the object's `this` in the handler, and can't figure out how to retrieve it from the event, you could initialize a bound version of `handler` in some `init` function:

```
obj = {
    handler: function(event) { /* handle the click; "this" is the object */ },

    draw: function() {
        this.elt.addEventListener('click', this.handler);
        //draw a bunch of stuff
    },

    undraw: function() {
        this.elt.removeEventListener('click', this.handler);
        //undraw a bunch of stuff
    },

    init: function() {
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
        return this;
    }
}.init();
```

Since `this.handler` is always identical to itself, this works as expected.

#### Using `EventListener`

A somewhat more elegant way to solve this problem is to pass to `addEventListener`, instead of a function, an object with the [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) interface, which is any object that implements the specially-named `handleEvent` method, which could be the 'this' object itself, so you can do:

```
obj = {
    handleEvent: function(event) {
        // "this" is the  object
        if (event.type === 'click') {
            // do stuff
        }
    },
    draw: function() {
        this.elt.addEventListener('click', this);
    },
    undraw: function() {
        this.elt.removeEventListener('click', this);
    }
};
```

Note the `this` being passed to `addEventListener`. In other words, we are passing the object itself, in its incarnation as an instance of `EventListener`, by virtue of its having implemented `handleEvent`. `handleEvent` is a full-fledged method of the object and as such has full access to all its methods and properties, and because `this` is identical to itself, the adding, adding again, and removing behavior works as you want.

I don't see this approach used very much, but it can make event handling more streamlined, especially if you add some sugar around it, such as arranging for individual methods to handle each event type:

```
obj = {
    handleEvent: function(event) {
        return this[event.type](event); // dispatch to method with name of event
    },
    click: function(event) {
        // handle click; "this" is obj
    },

    draw: function() { 
        this.elt.addEventListener('click', this); 
    },
    undraw: function() {
        this.elt.removeEventListener('click', this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to give this a shot. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Is the way I'm wanting to do it the most logical? With the event handlers etc? Should I consider a different approach?

Comment: Not quite sure what your asking--if you want to handle events, you need event handlers.

Comment: I like the first solution under what you titled **Event Listener** think that I approach was what I was trying to get at. I still haven't had a chance to try it. If all goes well I'll come back and give ya the green check. In the mean time +1 for all your time and effort!!

Comment: Ok, one follow up question I have: with your help, (and MDN docs) I've successfully created event listeners that _override_ themselves. **However**, I'd like the original listener to be discarded and be able to proceed with the new one. According to MDN the second listener is ignored: `If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded....`

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you mean by "event listeners that override themselves". If the behavior of the event listener has changed, there's no need to remove it and add it; it will continue to function, with whatever new behavior it has.

Comment: Well, what it's doing _is adding to the behavior_. I want to **remove** old behavior and only keep new behavior. I'm able to accomplish what I want with old style event listeners (`element.onclick = function(){...};`) and then "remove" their functionality like so `element.onclick = "";`. I'd rather not do it that way.

Comment: @torazaburo you should consider copy-pasting this into a tutorial with some little examples on HTML5 and perhaps legacy handling, I haven't found so well explained event handling anywhere here.