# Can't remove event listener from DOM element

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Can anyone tell me why the 'tileClick' event listener is not being removed at the bottom of this function? The code, in it's entirety, works and I get no error. I can even throw a console.log in the for loop and print out all the DOM elements. However, the event listener is staying put. I'm stuck!

```
function tileSelection(dieTotal) {
    var openTiles = document.getElementsByClassName('openTile'),
        dieAmountLeft = dieTotal;

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = dieAmountLeft;

    for(var i=0; i<openTiles.length; i++){
        openTiles[i].addEventListener('click',function tileClick(){
            // TODO: Must remove event listener!!!
            this.classList.toggle('selectedTile');
            if(this.classList.contains('selectedTile')){
                dieAmountLeft -= parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-tile-val'));
                if(dieAmountLeft >= 0){
                    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = dieAmountLeft;
                }else{
                    dieAmountLeft += parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-tile-val'));
                    this.classList.toggle('selectedTile');
                }
            } else {
                dieAmountLeft += parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-tile-val'));
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = dieAmountLeft;
            }
            if(dieAmountLeft === 0){
                for(var t=0; t<openTiles.length; t++){
                    openTiles[t].removeEventListener('click',tileClick);
                }
                newTurn();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try without the `tileClick` parameter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it needs the parameter. I do something similar in another method. However, this one I have in a for loop since it's on multiple elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update or Change or Remove/Reset Javascript event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007354/update-or-change-or-remove-reset-javascript-event-listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign the function using:

```
openTiles[i].addEventListener('click',function tileClick(){ ... }, ...)
```

The name of a named function expression is only available within the function itself, it is not made available to the enclosing execution context (except for [*buggy versions of IE*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs)).

If you want to remove a listener, you need to have a reference to it so you should do something like:

```
function titleClick(){...}
...
openTiles[i].addEventListener('click', tileClick, ...)
```

so that then when you remove the listener, you can get a reference to it as *titleClick*.

Since you are calling remove from within the function, it only has a reference to the instance of the function that is associated with that element, i.e. each instance of *titleClick* has a reference only to itself.

You are attaching a new instance of *openTile* to each element, so each only has a reference to itself so it will only remove it's own listener. Calling it on other elements has no effect since if *removeEventListener* doesn't find a matching function, it does nothing. The method has no return value so you can't tell whether it "worked" or not from the result of the call.

E.g. in the following, clicking on *foo 0* only removes the listener from itself, you have to click on the other button to remove its listener.

```
<button class="foo">foo 0</button>
<button class="foo">foo 1</button>

<script>
var foos = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('foo'));

foos.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click',function bar(){
    console.log('clicked on ' + this.textContent);
    foos.forEach(function(el) {el.removeEventListener('click', bar)});
  }, false);
});
</script>
```

Changing the script to:

```
var foos = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('foo'));

function bar(){
  console.log('clicked on ' + this.textContent);
  foos.forEach(function(el) {el.removeEventListener('click', bar)});
}

foos.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', bar, false);
});
```

fixes that because now there is only one instance of *bar* and each listener references the one instance. You can add as many buttons as you like, I just used two for this example.

Note that the use of `[].slice.call` with a host object is not recommended, it will fail in some browsers in use. I've used it for convenience, a for loop is much more reliable for converting an HTMLCollection to an array.

Comment: Ahhhh. OK. So, if I move the 'tileClick' function out of the for loop and then just pass what I need into it, via parameters. _That_ should work since there will then be only **one** instance of 'tileClick.' I was, essentially, creating several 'tileClick' functions since it was in the loop. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

assign your function to a variable

like

```
var myfunc = function () {}
```

then

do

```
openTiles[t].removeEventListener('click',myfunc);
```