# JavaScript removeEventListener won't work

Tags: javascript

I have a simple drag / drop script that I am playing around with to learn.. to try the code, just have an element with id "TEST" on a page and place the script on the page.

The element will begin dragging, and when you mouse up it seems like the removeEventListener doesn't seem to be working. I've been messing with it for 2 hours please help! Is there any obvious reason that it is not working? here is the script:

```
var Example = function()  {
var exa = this;
this.elem = null;

    this.init = function() {
        exa.elem = document.getElementById('TEST');
        console.log('exa.init()');
        exa.attachEvent(exa.elem, 'mousedown',  function(event) {
            console.log('mousedown');
            exa.drag.anchor(event);
        });

    }
    this.attachEvent = function ( object, event, handler )  {
            if (window.attachEvent) {
                    object.attachEvent( 'on'+event, function() {
                    handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false );
            } else {
                object.addEventListener( event, function() {
                handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false );
            }
        }
      this.detachEvent = function( object, event, handler ){
            if (window.detachEvent) {
                object.detachEvent( 'on'+event, function(){
                    handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false ) ;
            } else {
                    object.removeEventListener( event, function() {
                        handler.apply(object, arguments);
                    }, false );
            }
        }

    this.drag = {
        'release' : function(event) {
            exa.elem.removeEventListener('mousemove', function(event) { exa.drag.move(event) }, true);
            console.log('drag.release2');
        },
        'anchor' : function(event){
            console.log('exa.drag.anchor();');
            offY= event.clientY-parseInt(exa.elem.offsetTop);
            offX= event.clientX-parseInt(exa.elem.offsetLeft);
            exa.attachEvent(window, 'mousemove', function(event) {
                    exa.drag.move(event);
            });
        },
        'move' : function(event) {
            exa.elem.style.position = 'absolute';
            var topPosition = (event.clientY-offY);
            var leftPosition = (event.clientX-offX);
            exa.elem.style.top =  topPosition+ 'px';
            exa.elem.style.left =  leftPosition + 'px';
            //console.log('FROM THE TOP: ' + topPosition);
            //console.log('FROM THE LEFT: ' + leftPosition);
            exa.attachEvent(window, 'mouseup', function(event) {
                    exa.drag.release(event);
            });
        }
    }

}


var example = new Example();
example.attachEvent(window, 'load', function(event) {
  example.init(event);
});
```

---

**Sorry about that, the code I posted had confusing names for the functions and a couple mistakes, please look at the following:**

```
var Example = function()  {
var exa = this;
this.elem = null;

    this.init = function() {
        exa.elem = document.getElementById('TEST');
        console.log('exa.init()');
        exa.newEvent(exa.elem, 'mousedown',  function(event) {
            console.log('mousedown');
            exa.drag.anchor(event);
        });

    }
    this.newEvent = function ( object, event, handler )  {
            if (window.attachEvent) {
                    object.attachEvent( 'on'+event, function() {
                    handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false );
            } else {
                object.addEventListener( event, function() {
                handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false );
            }
        }
      this.removeEvent = function( object, event, handler ){
            if (window.detachEvent) {
                object.detachEvent( 'on'+event, function(){
                    handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false ) ;
            } else {
                    object.removeEventListener( event, function() {
                        handler.apply(object, arguments);
                    }, false );
            }
        }


    this.drag = {
        'release' : function(event) {
            exa.removeEvent(exa.elem, 'mousemove', exa.drag.move);
            console.log('drag.release2');
        },
        'anchor' : function(event){
            console.log('exa.drag.anchor();');
            offY= event.clientY-parseInt(exa.elem.offsetTop);
            offX= event.clientX-parseInt(exa.elem.offsetLeft);
            exa.newEvent(window, 'mousemove', function(event) {
                    exa.drag.move(event);
            });
        },
        'move' : function(event) {
            exa.elem.style.position = 'absolute';
            var topPosition = (event.clientY-offY);
            var leftPosition = (event.clientX-offX);
            exa.elem.style.top =  topPosition+ 'px';
            exa.elem.style.left =  leftPosition + 'px';
            exa.newEvent(window, 'mouseup', function(event) {
                    exa.drag.release(event);
            });
        }
    }

}


var example = new Example();
example.newEvent(window, 'load', function(event) {
  example.init(event);
});
```

Comment: you're adding mousemove to exa, and removing it from exa.elem

Comment: actually, you're using exa.attachEvent to add mousemove listener on window, and using exa.elem.removeEventListener to remove a different function (although it looks the same, it's not the same function) from mousemove

Comment: I posted a new code as I had some confusing names for the functions. I wasn't adding the mouseover to exa as it looked like I was doing. Please view the second code block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update or Change or Remove/Reset Javascript event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007354/update-or-change-or-remove-reset-javascript-event-listener)

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable that refers to first function (callback passed to addEventListener), each time when you passing function with body as argument to removeEventListener, new function is created

```
var callback = function()
{
    alert(1);
}

button.addEventListener('click', callback);
button.removeEventListener('click', callback);
```

Comment: I see what you're saying but I am having trouble figuring out how I would do this in my situation. Do you see in the this.drag.anchor() function where I am setting the following event listener: exa.newEvent(window, 'mousemove', function(event) {
                    exa.drag.move(event);
            });     How would I go about setting the callback variable as you are saying?  Thank you Alexander!