# How to remove a Javascript EventEmiiter arrow function callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events, eventemitter

My React code keeps triggering EventEmitter callbacks that should have been removed. When I inspect my React class that extends EventEmiiter, I found that the callbacks are still present in the *events* fields, even though *removeListener* has already been called on those callbacks.

I suspect this is happening because I add callbacks to the EventEmitter as arrow functions, but when I remove them, I do not. Removing them as arrow functions do not work. In my code below, FirebaseStore extends EventEmitter:

```
  _onFirebaseChange() {
    this.setState({
      refId: this.getRefId()
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    FirebaseStore.addChangeListener(() => this._onFirebaseChange());
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    FirebaseStore.removeChangeListener(this._onFirebaseChange);
  }
```

I need to use arrow functions because the change events (*_onFirebaseChange*), need access to *this.state*.

When I look at my source from Chrome dev tools, it's difficult for my to determine whether *addChangeListener* and *removeChangleListener* refer to the same callback:

```
key: 'componentDidMount',
value: function componentDidMount() {
  var _this2 = this;

  _FirebaseStore2.default.addChangeListener(function () {
    return _this2._onFirebaseChange();
  });
}
},{
key: 'componentWillUnmount',
value: function componentWillUnmount() {
  _FirebaseStore2.default.removeChangeListener(this._onFirebaseChange);
}}
```

Here is the relevant code from Firebase store:

```
addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(FIREBASE_CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(FIREBASE_CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
}
```

It would be possible to fix this with a closure, but I think that's overkill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update or Change or Remove/Reset Javascript event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007354/update-or-change-or-remove-reset-javascript-event-listener)

Comment: `()=>foo()` is different from `foo` - this is nothing to do with react as those functions just not equal and hence remove can't find one you want it to remove. There are plenty similar post that solve it for other events in JavaScript, probably someone will find good duplicate specific to react so.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `componentDidMount` method.

```
componentDidMount() {
   FirebaseStore.addChangeListener(this._onFirebaseChange);
}
```

The function needs to be binded directly.

Comment: This won't work - without a mod to the code above - due to the fact that I need access to *this.state* from the _onFirebaseChange function.

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple fix that I should have caught earlier. The closure solution Alexi posted would have also worked, but all that was missing was to bind * _onFirebaseChange* to *this* in the constructor.

So in the constructor of my React class, I added this line:

```
this._onFirebaseChange = this._onFirebaseChange.bind(this);
```

Then my *componentDidMount* function was able to refer to the same callback as *componentWillUnmount*, while also being able to access *this.state*.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    FirebaseStore.addChangeListener(this._onFirebaseChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    FirebaseStore.removeChangeListener(this._onFirebaseChange);
  }
```