# How to exclude Twitter Bootstrap on some descendants

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scope

I have to integrate some web objects through an API in a `Bootstrap` based site.
Meaning my objects come with their `CSS` and are encapsulated in "`Bootstrap elements`". I have tried to prefix `Bootstrap` with less (`.boot-scope`) but, because my objects are encapsulated in `Bootstrap nodes`, the cascading mechanism makes `Bootstrap` style to be applied on my objects also (at least the overlap). Scoping `Bootstrap` for a site subset using only `Bootstrap` works well, but my situation is the opposite: I want to exclude some elements that are inside `Bootstrap elements`. I've found some inelegant solutions (like flagging all "non api" objects and prefixing `Bootstrap` with .nonapi >.) Has someone found a consistent solution to exclude elements from `Bootstrap` styling when those elements sit inside `Bootstrap nodes`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `custom.css` file and include it after all the bootstrap files. That should overwrite the styles from the bootstrap API

Comment: Thanks Caweren, as far as I understand, loading order just affect if the style weight is the same. If my bootstrap add for example a margin on .myclass and margin is not defined in my custom.css then the margin is applied :-(

Comment: @user3844138 Isn't that always the case, regardless of using Bootstrap or any other CSS framework?

Comment: See this answer [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only) for a complete explanation

Comment: @Dreamonic, yes you're right, it is not specific to BS

Comment: @Caweren, understand the reset but it doesn't really help in my situation. Regarding a potential solution: I can recompile my bootstrap but can't touch css coming from the "API objects", I can tag top level div's containing API objects.