# How set the style of the content to default

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb foundation 3 custom for layout(Grid) and style. Based on the user who is logged in, I need to remove the Zurb styling for some content. But I would like to still keep using the zurb layout.

How can I reset all properties of an element to default value.

[image]

Only for the main content of the page I want to set it to default, other part should still use zurb styling.

CSS:

```
    input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], textarea {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

input[type="text"].oversize, input[type="password"].oversize, input[type="date"].oversize, input[type="datetime"].oversize, input[type="email"].oversize, input[type="number"].oversize, input[type="search"].oversize, input[type="tel"].oversize, input[type="time"].oversize, input[type="url"].oversize, textarea.oversize {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="date"]:focus, input[type="datetime"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="time"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, textarea:focus {
  background: #fafafa;
  outline: none !important;
  border-color: #b3b3b3;
}

input[type="text"][disabled], input[type="password"][disabled], input[type="date"][disabled], input[type="datetime"][disabled], input[type="email"][disabled], input[type="number"][disabled], input[type="search"][disabled], input[type="tel"][disabled], input[type="time"][disabled], input[type="url"][disabled], textarea[disabled] {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="four columns">
                        <label for="txtName">* First Name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fourteen columns ">
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtName" type="text" maxlength="25" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName" class="eight" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have to do this for all controls not just input.

Rendered HTML(View source):

Comment: can you share your HTML/CSS code

Comment: You can assign a class to that specific element and use this code:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15903168/1552518

Comment: I have added the css and html. Please take a  look.

Comment: You know Foundation 5 is out right ...

Comment: @martialdidit Yes I do. But I need to do this using Foundation 3 due to the requirements

Comment: @Vahi I feel bad for you, so frustrating

Comment: @Haimrich I tried it, but this removes the initial style too. I just get a blank input with no border etc.
I want the browser style to be present