# I need and inline style code to eliminate wordpress template styling css

Tags: css, wordpress, external, inline-styles

I need a code that is something like:

```
<div style="templateCSS:none">Content that has mysterious WordPress template CSS applied on it</div>
```

I don't want to override it with another inline style, I just want everything removed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use the CSS3 keyword `initial` for every property of the element. Something like this:

### HTML

```
<div class="reset-style">Content that has mysterious WordPress template CSS applied on it</div>
```

### CSS

```
.reset-style{
    margin : initial;
    margin-bottom : initial;
    margin-left : initial;
    margin-right : initial;
    margin-top : initial;
    /* All the css properties*/
}
```

Check this answer: [Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be inline styling, not external.

Comment: and if you try put it into the same file with the tags <style></style>, is It not useful?, does it have to be inline necessarily
?

Comment: Yes. I tried implementing your code inline and it didn't work. Thanks for offering your help. I need a code that releases external css styling, but I guess it doesn't exist.