# CSS Breaking Report

Tags: jquery, html, css, crystal-reports-2010

I'm creating a webpage which uses global css and a crystal report.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    <br />
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crViewer" HasDrilldownTabs="false" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false" CssClass="none" ToolPanelView="None" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The global css breaks the report causing the toolbar to look mangled. Are there any tags
or ways to block the outside global css from getting to the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to go through all the CSS affecting that DIV element using something like Chrome's Dev Tools and add an id to the div and apply CSS to that id to change or reset the specific CSS rules that causing you an issue.

More along the lines of what you are looking for you could reset just about all CSS rules for that element like shown in the answer for this post [Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, unfortunately css is not "smart". If you don't want the css to get to that element, the only way you are really gonna be able to do it is by adding another css rule somewhere (give it the id of the element) and undo the css that is affecting it.

In css the last thing that is applied to the element is what is shown, so if you undo all the css changes to the element after the include of your global css then those css changes will take precedence.