# Stop jQuery UI theme overwriting custom theme

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, datepicker

We use the jQuery UI datepicker control at work, and have only taken the .ui-datepicker classes and customised them.

We don't actually use the jQuery UI themes at all.

The issue I'm having now is I want to use the jQUERY UI dialog box with one of the themes (redmond) or equally roll my own if I knew which parts of the CSS I need.

When I use redmond, it's now adding lots of css classes to the page that the datepicker probably shares with the rest of the UI, and effectively completely screws up the calendar.

Is there any way to isolate the CSS for datepicker or is there any where I can see precisely what CSS i need to add to my project outside of themes in order to have the dialog work properly?

Comment: How about preventing the built in CSS from overriding  the custom css for datepicker with `!important`..?

Comment: You can use [a CSS reset as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030), or if you use `less` you can use [its `@import` extensions](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options). The question is a bit vague, so can't really be more specific. You might want to re-tag it with `css` and include a bit more detail