# Jquery Widget CSS conflicts with third-party site

Tags: css, jquery-widgets

I have created one Jquery widgets which is used in many third party website.

My Widgets has it's own css for widgets elements. It is working perfect when run independently.

But when i add my Widget to 3rd party website, my widgets css inherit or take from 3rd party CSS.

How can resolve this issue as i don't aware about 3rd party css?

```
#my-div * {
    animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;

...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope your css to your widget's html.

For example create a wrapper for your widget:

```
<div class="my-widget">
    <!-- Widget Content Here -->
</div>
```

Then style everything inside your widget as a descendant of your my-widget class.

```
.my-widget .widget-text {
    color: green;
}
```

Don't style anything with elements - so don't do

```
p {
    /* Style here */
}
```

Only use classes all scoped to your .my-widget class.

As per your comment if you are still getting problems you could add a reset within your widgets scope:

```
.my-widget * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    /* Etc */
}
```

Comment: You're right and I have done the same but extra css that i don't have defined, have been inherited from third-party website and i don't won't them  so how to handle it?

Comment: I have update CSS as you told  : #my-div * { all set to default },  but it removes all the CSS of my widget. i have added it at top of all css. I h ave added all this attributes :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Comment: Have you put the reset at the top of the css file? Please edit your question to show the exact code you are using.

Comment: I have updated code. I don't have added reset. but add as shown  in my code

Comment: I could do with seeing all the code - the HTML and all the CSS - to help further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71083/discussion-between-simon-mason-and-yatin-mistry).