# Not to style an entire div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

If I have a div with a `class='myDiv'` or something is it then possible to make a not selector in a stylesheet not to style anything inside that div?

In my particular case I'm talking tables, th, tr and td's inside that div.

```
table:not([class='myDiv'])

thead tr:not([class='myDiv'])

tr:not([class='myDiv'])

td:not([class='myDiv'])
```

Something similar to that so that the styling in question doesn't affect the elements within the div with that class?

Edit: In my previous questions you can probably see what I am trying to do. The problem is I want to change an external stylesheet (that is used all over the website) in such a way that it still works as it does now for the rest of the website, but should not style my calendar tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot reference the parent element.
Go the other way around:

```
.allOtherClasses:not(.specialClassDiv) table{
        /*
        Anything here will style the TABLE elements inside .allOtherClasses
        but not the TABLE inside .specialClassDiv
        */
}
```

Comment: Great. Looks like we are on the right path. If I have something like table:not([name='start_time']), thead, tbody, th, td, tr { already. How would that look like here when I would need to both avoid my own class and this name?

Comment: what means *my own class*? Can you please add more details? it's a bit unclear...

Comment: @gerre `table:not([name='start_time']), thead, tbody, th, td, tr {` i think this is completely wrong, cause i.e. the `thead` selector will reference to **every possible `thead`** in your DOM. I'm not sure this is what you want...

Comment: I have added a bit to the original post. Hope you can understand it?

Comment: @gerre the simplest thing you could do is to put your calendar into a separate .html file, and call it into your page using `<iframe src="calendar.html"></iframe>` Now your iframe-calendar styles will not get messed up by any stylesheet.

Comment: @gerre otherwise, if you want to reset one element's styles to default... will be hard to accomplish, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only - means you'll have to add a `.reset-this` to every possible element inside your parent element...

Comment: Ok. I must look into some off these possible solutions. At least I have made some progress with the problem.