# Display HTML mail message in a web page without breaking this page style

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to display mail messages in a web page.  These mail message are comming from an exchange server and contain a bunch of style elements.

When i load these mail in a div, those style elements break my own page style by overriding some of them.

Is there a way to load an html mail body in isolation from the page in which it'll be loaded?  (and without Iframes of course).

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the style for this div only so it wont break your own CSS.

You should look at this post :

[Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Comment: It solve only half of my problem...  I also need to display the mail with it's own css so if remove the css, the mail will look flat (or even will be altered by my own CSS).

Comment: Can we have the part of your code where you include this mail ?

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution would be to insert mail's html content within a div having a specific id (ie id="foo") and then, process the style of the mail content to add that id before each class declaration in the mail.

All classes declared within the mail will look like this:

```
#foo H1{
...
}

#foo body{
...
}
```

Then, the scope of this classses will only be the id in which the mail body was injected.

I'm still looking for the cleanest way to do this (Jquery, Rivets, etc.)...