# Is there a way to get default css settings or reset it?

Tags: css

I am working on a website that already has general properties on the `<table>` tag element (in the whole website).

So if I add a table in a specific page after building it on a blank html page, it gets the properties of the global `<table>`.

How do I reset it's properties of the table element just for this specific page?

When adding the code ansered in this post:

[Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

to my table class... for example:

```
.ext{
*here*
}

<table class="ext"> 
 ...... 
</table>
```

It has too many properties that makes it worse to run over the older properties.

I'm sure there is a better way to do these kind of stuff. Please help.

Comment: Are you able to set the style properties as `!important` in the `.ext { }` ?

Comment: The default CSS rules inherited from the browser can only be overridden by other rules declared by the site. There are many [relatively concise reset stylesheets](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) out there.

Comment: You could utilize [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)

Comment: Why don't you just define the CSS properties for `table.ext`?  You probably only need a handful of properties at most and the rest (those not being used) can stay as is.

Comment: I can, but I have other stuff like background properties that don't display the background because if this.@BenClarke

Comment: I just don't think there is a practic solution for this :S

Comment: If you are saying about the browser defaults than look at CSS reset stylesheets, they are all over the web, those stylesheets reset each elements properties to a standardized value.

Few Examples

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ (CSS Reset With HTML5 Elements Included)

Comment: Yeah I know about these.. the problem is when you have properties like background, colors, vertically align, ect. 

I just thought there is something much easier and time saving to do in these situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the web, there are a lot of files that have all the configuration and all the css properties set to default, just use one and see the results.

You can see an overview here: http://cssreset.com/

Comment: So there is no awesome trick for that.. <.<
Already tried these :/ 
But tnx.