# How can remove all style property of class from span using css?

Tags: css

I'm using social API which is dynamically adding the class on `<a></a>`. I want to remove all style property of dynamically add class.

### CSS

```
a.api_sytle{

    background-image: url(https://s-passets.pinimg.com/images/pidgets/pinit_bg_en_rect_gray_20_1.png)!important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
    background-repeat: none!important;
    background-size: 40px 60px!important;
    height: 20px!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    vertical-align: baseline!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    width: 40px!important;
    background-position: 0 -20px;
}
#pin-socail{
    all: unset;
    }
```

I searched about it and find this style property `all: unset;` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only), but it does not work.

### HTML

```
<li><a id="pin-socail" href="www.test.api-response.com"></a></li>
```

Can any one guide me is there possible that i remove the all style from dynamically added class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
#pin-socail{
  all: initial;
 }
```

if this still doesn't work then you can try with `!important` keyword. i.e:

```
#pin-socail{
  all: initial!important;
 }
```

Here is one demo: http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/LVxvWP