# cordova value of selected option before select

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova

Heyall,

For a few days I have been getting the following problem:
[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2fvN.png)

The image shows two bars. It only is shown like this in a built version of Cordova on iOS or Android. Not in if ran in the browser, so I can't inspect the attribute.

The second bar (with no caps) is the `select` attribute. What the first bar is, God may know. But God hasn't yet been so kind to tell me. Does anyone know why it is there and is styled as is? Even without any css it still shows. I only want to show the second bar, obviously. But the first one won't disappear. It always shows the selected `option` of the `select` below.

I have tried 'cleaning' the css of the `select` ([Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)) but this hasn't worked. Also assigning select:before other properties won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have been able to solve this by removing jquery-mobile v1.4.5. How exactly jquery-mobile caused this problem to occur, I don't know. But by exchanging jquery-mobile by fastclick.js I do get the functionality I want, but without the bugs/unintended features.