# Override a CSS rule (needs to be delete)

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I do not have access to the HTML file and we use a CDN for jQuery (so assume I don't have access to that as well).

How do I go about "deleting" a rule using my own custom CSS? I am attaching a picture with the CSS rule I want deleted.

This is how it looks:
[image: with radio buttons]

This is how I want it to look:

[image: without radio buttons]

Comment: You can just load your own stylesheet after that of jQuery mobile's CSS, and override the background property.

Comment: I understand that you can override it... but I don't want a background position at all. Is that possible?

Comment: `background-position` is used in conjunction with `background-image`, usually. You can simply set the latter to none.

Comment: As a side-note, all styles have a "default" value.  When you say "delete", you really just want to set it to the "default".  So, for example (per @Terry comment) - you can reset the background image (which is *really* what you want to remove) to "none": `background-image: none;`

Comment: Thank you guys! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the `background-position` to have no effect on the position of the image, use this:

```
.ui-icon-radio-off {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

But if you want to reset it to what it was supposed to be set to if that default jquery css wasn't there, then you can unset it like this:

```
.ui-icon-radio-off {
    background-position: initial;
}
```

**N.B.** You mgiht have to add an `!important` tag to the above properties if jquery renders the css property below the above property.

Comment: Given that you have no idea what the "initial" value was, it seems safer to use "none" instead.

Comment: @cale_b `background-position` doesn't accept a `none` value though. And do edit my answer with the correct definition of what inital does and I'll approve it if it's correct. Cheers

Comment: True enough.  I misread your answer - what the OP (I believe) is really after is background-image none....

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers accept the [`all`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all) CSS definition. What it does it resets or reverts all the CSS definition for all elements matching the CSS selector.

```
.my-class {
    all: none;
}
```

Here is an good example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31317986/3856582

```
#someselector {
    all: initial;
    * {
        all: unset;
    }
}
```

Or use the CSS `initial` keyword on any CSS definition.