# How do I reset all css styles for a certain div? (Jekyll blog)

Tags: javascript, css, jekyll

I need to create a timeline. I'm using this timeline https://github.com/ybogdanov/history-timeline which is a JavaScript timeline.

I did read this post and tried all of its solutions
[Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

I cannot make my embed timeline working :(

This is the html with the timeline only

[image]

This is the blog (Jekyll based)

[image]

Comment: Whats wrong? Please post your code, I don't really understand your question. divs will only inherit their parent properties, or some could have inherit styles based on the content.. please post code!

Comment: A repository url can be helpful to debug.

Comment: I'm gonna see how to post without compromising the thesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: an explanation to what is the problem and how is your solution fixing it would be helpful than just some code snippet.

Comment: thanks, I have quoted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only that suggests that and more ... but with Jekyll it does not work

Comment: I'm gonna see how to post without compromising the thesis