# Convert LESS to CSS and use it with Jekyll

Tags: css, sass, less, jekyll

In a previous post ([How do I reset all css styles for a certain div? (Jekyll blog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809560/how-do-i-reset-all-css-styles-for-a-certain-div-jekyll-blog?noredirect=1#comment64993287_38809560)) I did ask about a timeline that losses its style when I use it with my Jekyll site.

I did try to us an iframe but that is not a good solution for mobile.

My timeline is based on this project: https://github.com/ybogdanov/history-timeline. That timeline uses LESS to provide styles.

**The problem is that Jekyll uses SASS instead of CSS.**

This is my modified less style that works perfect with an iframe:

```
#content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

#ruler {
  top: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: top 0.1s linear;
}

#chart {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

svg {
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .axis text {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

I used a LESS to CSS converter and I get this:

```
#content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
#ruler {
  top: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: top 0.1s linear;
}
#chart {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
svg .axis path,
svg .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
svg .axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

But some lines give me a warning about "unknown property" and the styles are missing when I insert the timeline using a `div`.

What can I do? I only wonder about having a readable text.

Timeline with iframe:

[image]

Timeline with div:

[image]

Comment: You're still not provide code to debug. A piece of css code is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [original file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ybogdanov/history-timeline/master/public/style/style.less) only use LESS for some indentation and should work with Sass, just rename the file and put it in the `_sass` folder, so that Jekyll can build it.

```
mv styles.less timeline.scss && mv timeline.scss _sass
```

Create a `css/main.scss` file with:

```
---
---

@import "timeline";
```

In your layout or your include file, you should link to the the generated `main.css` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I did try this as well as `lessc style.less style.css` from terminal. The problem is that both create a css file with unknown elements that are ignored by any browser.

Comment: @manetsus, thanks for pointing, I updated my answer, I hope it is more useful.