# whole page with a style with one image original color

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with the whole page in style

```
<div class="w3-sand w3-grayscale w3-large">
```

How can I make the image xxx showing original color instead of w3-grayscale?

```
<img src="xxx">
```

Comment: it seems that you are following the w3schools tutorial?

Comment: @Ashishsah yes I am

Comment: can you give me the link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only I think this could help

Comment: @Ashishsah https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_cafe

Comment: @Bolphgolph I'm trying to put img into <div class="yui3-cssreset"> </div> but it still is gray ...

Comment: it should not come under the parent class @sean

Comment: @Ashishsah but I don't want to change <div class="w3-sand w3-grayscale w3-large">, how to make <img> showing original color?

Comment: as mentioned in my answer . make a div outside of the parent class

Comment: You have to use `position:absolute` that will be much complex..so just partition the div remove it outside from the parent

Comment: @Ashishsah I still want the rest of page to be gray, all pictures are still gray, but just one picture showing original color

Comment: just make that out parent and adjust it. After that yiu can again wrap up the next content in greyscale class

Comment: @Ashishsah the img is still gray even if I wrote for it filter: grayscale(0%);

Comment: @Ashishsah how to pull img out of div class? this img is within 5 layers of div class, I already give u the link of the source code. The reason why I say your answer is useless is because I'd rather someone tell me the technique to implement in order to make it work, not abstract concept such as pull it out. Sometimes it sounds easy, but I am handling code here. If your implementation works, it will be proved by itself to be useful.

Comment: wait you gave me the link of w3school not of your source code...and i have told you the concept that you need to pull it out from that div...you are a beginner that why you are thinking it is a Sisyphean task...but it is dam easy

Comment: we are just making the comment section long...ashishsah1000@gmail.com reach me out in mail with your problem i can surely guide you

Comment: @Ashishsah in the code where you find this <div class="w3-sand w3-grayscale w3-large">, which gives the rest of page a gray effect. 6 lines after it, you probably see this text: "The Cafe was founded ...", all I'm doing is to add <img src="xxx"> before this text, without any gray effect to the img itself. Hope I make the point clear this time.

Comment: @Ashishsah I found the solution. Your method cannot make sure the whole page is using the same format because once you break it in the middle, it messes up things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a beginner:
W3Schools have their own stylesheet, Let me explain you are the style here in the classes of `w3-sand,w3-large,w3-greyscale`

```
.w3-sand, .w3-hover-sand:hover {
    color: #000!important;
    background-color: #fdf5e6!important;
}

.w3-large {
    font-size: 18px!important;
}
.w3-greyscale, .w3-grayscale {
    filter: grayscale(75%); /* this is the line of code applying the filter */
}
```

so these are the style of the specific classes mentioned there...
To remove the image from the `greyscalse` you can use remove it from the parent or you can remove the  `greyscalse`style from the `parent div`. As it is the one who is applying the effect on the child element. So just break down your code or remove the style from the parent element.

Comment: Your answer is useless because I need to only make one img inside the class not grayscale, but everything else is grayscale

Comment: I have told you the ans you have to pull it out from the parent...thats only the solution... enclose the div before the image and then put the image...and then you can again start your greyscale div

Comment: Or learn to use `position: absolute;` thats only the solution else

Comment: My ans is usefull because i explained what you have to do...that is only the solution else you would have got the ans till now on this big community

Comment: give me your mail i am sending you my way

Comment: leave it...i hope this solves your problem...I have replaced the images with a single image

Comment: https://jsbin.com/qopicitocu/edit?html,output  @Sean have a look that what i said

Comment: I don't think this make the new img fit properly into existing style. If you change the img to 100px wide, you will find that it has its own background, it is sitting on its own line. The img is supposed to be small, and positioned in front of the text naturally, which means it fits into existing style. If you drag the img out of existing div, it looks like breaking existing style.

Comment: simple in one line...you are saying that i will not have my parents characteristics...and that never possible...if you feel that background is diffrent give it a same color...that's how it works...else you can never get what you want...child will inherit the parent characteristics