# Show preview of HTML with original CSS inside an existing site

Tags: html, css

**Goal**

I have to show a preview of an HTML file with its own CSS inside a modal dialog of my site.

**Problem**
My site has its css and i don't want it to affect the preview. The html to show has only "style" attribute, no css class selector defined.

Is there a way to reach it? 
I thought [this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

```
#reset-modal-content{
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

But i've found that if i comment a style attribute, the element gets "my site" definition.

Comment: use `iframe` for this

Comment: Ok got it, i thought there was a way to avoid iframe. Thanks.

Comment: you can but why complicating when it's easy

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you.

Comment: Or an image...?