# Use another css framework for certain sections

Tags: css

Is it possible to limit a framework's css classes to certain sections?

I want to include some components from the materialize framework into an existing wordpress theme that uses the exact same class names. Going through the whole materialize css file and renaming every single file would be too much work and wouldn't work anyway as I also need classes like `table`.

I thought about using iframes but they're a real pain when it comes to responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Are these on a single page?  If that is that is the case, you will have to rename elements for one framework or the other.

If they are on different pages you might load one CSS file depending on which framework you wish to apply on that particular page.

Out of curiosity I tried this

```
    <style>
        .test{
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
    <p class="test">Will this be red?</p>
    <style>
        .test{
            color:black;
        }
    </style>
    <p class="test">This may be black</p>
```

It didn't work

Comment: Something like this was potentially possible with the use of the `scoped` attribute on the `style` element (initially part of the HTML5 spec). This allowed the styles to be confined to the scope of the parent element (so you would also need an outer container). However, browser support was sparse and it has since been removed from later versions of the HTML5 spec.

Answer (score 1):

I partly solved it by writing a dirty python script that prepends a custom class name (in my case 
`.material`) to each style in the framework.

I then put the material design cards inside a `.material` div container and it seems to work for the most part.

I also tried to reset all of the theme styles inside the `material` container by using [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only). Though that doesn't seem to affect it.

Somehow it still doesn't work for the tables. I even set the `!important` flag to each table style but there's no effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to excluded elements additional class, and use for it CSS rules with `!important`. On this way you'll force that excluded elements take only CSS you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this snippet might answer your question.

This shows how the different CSS elements works when assigning the same class to all elements. You can then easily control each element with one class e.g. assign this class to the wrapping `<div>` and assign no class to the containing elements but define them in the CSS.

```css
.test {
 background: blue;
}

.test table {
 background: red;
}

.test p {
 background: yellow;
}

.test div {
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
<tr>
<td>Hello</td>
<td><p class="test">Hello too</p></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p class="test">Oh no</p>
<div class="test"><p class="test">Omfg</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this would be downloading the source files for the framework and compiling a customized version suited to your use case. You can modify the generated class names and remove the parts of the framework you won't be using, leading to a much smaller .css file containing unique class names.