# How to restore all element's styles to default?

Tags: css

I was wondering, is it possible to restore all styles to default?

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
  <h1>Should be bold</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

In this example I'm expecting that solution make h-tag bold, with default font-size and margins(problem bigger than just h-tag, i wanna all tags inside div to be restored to defaults :) ).

I've tried both `all: initial` and `all: unset`, but these approaches just reset styles, when I want to restore them to defaults.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a style reset css. If you make some research on google you will find what do you search.

Comment: Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Comment: @MehdiAyari, doesn't work :(

Comment: you are looking for `revert`

Comment: @Sfili_81, I've searched, and found nothing that resolves this case. As I mentioned in my question, I wanna restore defaults, and not reset styles.

Comment: You can just comment out the font and font-size. It should show you the text in default style then.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, still doesn't help https://jsfiddle.net/2fwpo3r1/

Comment: works only on Firefox for now (read the duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, okay, but how to solve it in Chrome?

Comment: you have to wait or re-think your CSS to avoid having this situation. Actually `revert` is the only value that can help you but it lack support

Comment: @TemaniAfif, oh, okay, thank you :(

Comment: You can use JavaScript to disable your stylesheet altogether, if that's what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/mcf7x23b/