# How to apply only custom properties to an element?

Tags: css

In very simple html/css, I have my menu in a `<table id="menu">`. The menu has no border, however I would like all the other tables in my blog to have borders.

I made it work this way:

```
#menu, #menu th, #menu td {border: none; color: red}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

However this is not very robust. If I add something else to `tables` I might forget to 'reset' it in #menu. Is there a way to force all properties in #menu so that I don't have to override one by one anything I would add to `table, th, td {...}`?
I tried the `:not()` selector but it doesn't feel robust either, I would rather specify what I want for menu on the `#menu {...}` line, not elsewhere. Let me know if that makes sense or I can reformulate

Comment: If you think that this method isn't very robust and want to find a better way, I recommend getting a css refresher at something like w3 schools. If I understand what you are saying in that you want the properties in #menu to be default, you should just switch the code in the #menu and the table.

Comment: @oriont sorry I didn't explain well. I don't want the properties in #menu to be default. I want my #menu's table to NOT use properties defined in table{}, without having to override each of them

Comment: Why are you using a table for your menu? Use a div with a ul instead, then you don't have to override table styles. If this isn't an option you can create override classes that are specifically named like "no-border".

Comment: @NathanielFlick I kept my question short but the fact that it is a table or a ul or a div doesn't matter ; I'm looking for a generic way to not have to worry about what I'm doing. (in my case I want to write tables on all my blog posts without having to write a class on them, those style has to be the default, and the menu the exception under its identifier)

Comment: Use divs and you won't have to worry about unsetting table styles, you can just use classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I understand now. I was searching for a way to unset all values for a css class and came across this page: [Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

It tells us that we can do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
#menu, #menu th, #menu td {
  all: unset;
  color: red;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Notice how I added the `all: unset;` and removed the `border: none;`

This should reset all the styles for elements with that id, but make sure to put your other styles AFTER the all: unset, or else it will unset the styles you just wrote. Hope this helps!

Comment: this is in the spirit of what I wanted (and I didn't know about this 'all' selector) however it doesn't work well
See for instance the menu in the bottom right (appears after 5 secs) at https://jannaud.fr/guide-pour-passer-facilement-son-site-web-en-mode-sombre-dark-mode-css . It is called #slider in the css, you can easily uncheck in the inspector the rule  `#slider, #slider th, #slider td {border: none}` (workaround for the unset)

Comment: I didn't realize that you already had other styling for that table. In that case, what you already had, ```border: none;``` would be the only way to unset the border for that element, as there is no other way to unset it automatically. Sorry! Although I hope this isn't too much of an inconvenience since it is only 1 line.

Comment: no worries, thanks for checking and thanks for the help. At least it gives a clear answer even if it is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using *classes* instead of *id's*.

If you use a class you can apply a css rule to all elements that have It

So for example to your table you can use

```
.custum-table
```

The prevoius class Will apply css styles to all elements

And finally if you wanna apply another css rule you can add another class to your element in this way

*Another html file*

```
.custom-table__no--effect
```

Previous class with *BEM* Will apply css styles to only one element for example `table` element

Comment: thanks for the answer. If I understand right: does it mean that I need to add a class "normal_table" to ALL my tables (except the one in the menu)? If so it will be a bit cumbersome

Comment: Yeah it should be more effective @Thomas