# Removing all the existing CSS properties defined for Mobile view

Tags: css

I am using a 3rd party Library components in my project. The library provides components that has some styling defined for mobile devices.

I want to **OVERRIDE** those all properties in my code.
By "override" I mean I want to remove all the properties that are defined for `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)`.

How can I remove all those properties at once?

Comment: You can't _remove_ CSS (other than to not include it in the first place). What you can do is to use higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in order to override the existing rules with your own. I would first check the documentation of your third party components, however. Maybe there is some option to turn off the built-in CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a good editor.It is **notepad++**.
Get it here: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.6/

1. open your css file using Notepad++,
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>(to find) all properties under **@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)**,
3. Click **Find All in current document** or **Find All in All opened documents** according to your need,
4. Click on **Replace** Tab next to **find** tab.
5. Replace all words that you want in opened document.