# Is there a way to use common css in learnr tutorials?

Tags: r, learnr

In the learnr R package, one suggestion for distribution is to bundle up [tutorials into a package](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/publishing.html). However, to include custom css for a tutorial, it seems to require putting your .css file inside the unique subdirectory associated with each tutorial as:

```
+ inst/
|  + tutorials/
|  |  +- tutorial_A/
|  |  |  +- tutorial_A.rmd
|  |  |  +- custom.css
|  |  +- tutorial_B/
|  |  |  +- tutorial_B.
|  |  |  +- custom.css
```

The css file can be included with the yaml argument `css: custom.css`. Is there a way to simply put a single `custom.css` file in a higher-level directory (say as `inst/tutorials/custom.css` if it is shared by both tutorials? I've tried both relative and absolute paths, and nothing seems to work including the rather exotic yaml
`css: !expr system.file("tutorials/custom.css", package="my_package")`.

Note: I'm referring to an installed package and a tutorial loaded with `learnr::run_tutorial('tutorial_A', 'my_package')`. Simply running the Rmarkdown itself works.

Answer (score 3):

as far as I'm aware the css file has to be within the tutorial environment [in a folder called css](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/index.html#External_Resources). I've been working on a package of learnr tutorials recently, and haven't found a way to work from a single style sheet across multiple tutorials.

Comment: This was the answer for me :)

Answer (score 2):

After much struggle, a partial solution is to create an html file that includes the desired css. For example, `custom-css.html` placed in `inst/tutorials/`. In my case, `custom-css.html` is simply a wrapper for the css as

```
<style type="text/css">

... all desired css ...

</style>
```

Then, one can include this in the knitted tutorial via standard yaml frontmatter

```
output: 
  learnr::tutorial:
    includes:
      in_header: !expr system.file("tutorials/custom-css.html",package="my_package")
```

This fix is only partial because the learnr `tutorial-format.htm` template includes the `in_header` files earlier than css files. Thus, some default css cannot be modified in this fashion.

Comment: This worked for me and can be combined with this list of CSS reset/removals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only