# how to Unstyle html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a chrome extension which injects a script in a web-page. The script creates a element(div) and appends it to the "body" element. Now as you can see I am in no control of the styles. So, is there a way to un-style or a work-around?

I did look around but every solution required me to know which css styles needs to be changed. Is it possible to get a list of styles applied? And if it is possible to get a list, how can I know what are default values for the styles?

Comment: Is this only in a specific site or multiple?

Comment: @charlietfl multiple!

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for: [Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only). You can either append a `<style>` tag to the end of the `<head>` element and give your `<div>` a `class`, or use inline styles by saying `myDiv.style.color = "initial";` but change `color` to be anything

Comment: Another option which is a bit more complex is use a [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: @Charlietfl, I will look into it thanks!!

Comment: I think the question should be re-opened... Here is a solution I didn't have the time to post: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NWjGvXe?editors=1111)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Post it on the main question. Also, it doesn't work in Firefox: https://imgur.com/a/kzxzcXg

Comment: @Samathingamajig: Good point about FF... Thanks.