# CSS is overriding styles, any way to remove styling?

Tags: html, css, primefaces

my question is not that simple as it sounds i would say,

i just get into a Project from the state where we have to extend an existing webapp, the Project is quite messy with global imported .css libraries which are overriding themself,

since the application is quite big and there is like no way to refactor this mess in a fast manner, i have no way other then life with it and do my job,

since the classes are overriding my elements and are making a mess of them, is there any way to disable or avoid styling of my elements?

small note, we are using primefaces which is also not the modern way i would say, but in case this info is needed, here it is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this post, the "revert" parameter in ea. css style will revert the style to its origin value,

exmp:

```
height: revert;
max-height: revert;
width: revert;
max-width: revert;
```

etc.

it will not remove any styling from any library but it will at least override it and put it back to its origin value