# Disable CSS Styling for all elements in specific div?

Tags: html, css

My script generates a user's email signature and then displays it in a popup modal. The issue I have is that the `modal-body` div is also subject to the view's CSS styling which messes with the look and feel of the signature, hence I would like to disable CSS to get an unstyled look at the signature.

Is it possible to disable CSS styling for all elements in the `modal-body` div (p, br, a href, etc.) and how does one best go about this?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you give `position absolute` to that div and keep it outside of the`main div`inside the body that has all the CSS

Comment: @Ashishsah I don't think that would solve the problem of normal site styles conflicting with the modal though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various CSS reset values you can use with the [`all` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) to set the value of almost every property.

```css
.modal-body {
  all: initial | unset | revert
}
```

- `initial` value for property default values
- `unset` value for property default or inherit if an inherited property
- `revert` for default value for that element (browser styles), I think the only difference here would be that display would be block instead of inline for a div element.

The example above would only style the `.modal-body` itself though, if you want to reset values for every single element within it as well you could do the following:

```css
.modal-body,
.modal-body * {
  all: initial | unset | revert
}
```

This will not only target `.modal-body` but every descendant of `.modal-body`. Be careful with a value other than `unset` for this though as it's extremely powerful, and with great power comes great responsibility.

If you're still having issues, your other styles might be more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and therefore override this rule. You could try and add `!important` however that would necessitate using it on every re-style of elements in your modal. In this case I would suggest giving your modal an ID and using that to style it, and combing through your other CSS to remove ID selectors flattening the specificity.

Not sure I fully understand your comment... If this is not the HTML you meant, please update your question to contain your HTML and I'll update this answer:

```html
<div id="modalSignaturePreview">
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>
```

Anyways for the above HTML you can target it in CSS with `#modalSignaturePreview .modal-body`, here we're targeting all elements with a class of modal-body that are a descendant of any element with an ID of modalSignaturePreview

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. Bonus question: how could I apply this only to the `.modal-body` class inside the modal with `id = "modalSignaturePreview"`? Sorry, I work very little with CSS >.<

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the `all` css property.

```css
.modal-body * {
  all: initial;
}
```

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/9btawdfx/4/)

Should return everything to before it was modified with CSS at all.
The specificity for `.modal-body *` is only 0 1 0 though, so you may need to make this selector more specific or add `!important`.

Comment: I forgot about specificity, good point